# How to define multiple tasks in a single function and use in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="demo" onclick="tasks("fade")">
   <div id="demo" onclick="tasks("glow")">
    <div id="demo" onclick="tasks("slide")">
       <script>
       function tasks(){
           fade = do fade;
           glow =  make glows;
           slide = move slide; 
       }
       </script>
```

How to use single function and declare multiple tasks and use them specific element like I have create above?

Comment: how to put multiple function on single onclick with diffrent tasks and same action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, although it can be done in many other ways.

```js
function tasks(action){
 if(action === "fade"){
   console.log("Handle fade action here");
 }
 else if(action === "glow"){
    console.log("Handle glow action here");
 }
 else if(action === "slide"){
   console.log("Handle slide action here");
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" onclick="tasks('fade')">fade</div>
 <div id="demo" onclick="tasks('glow')">glow</div>
<div id="demo" onclick="tasks('slide')">slide</div>
```

Use `switch`:

```js
function tasks(action){
  switch(action){
  
     case "fade": console.log("Fade action here");
                  break;
      
     case "glow": console.log("Glow action here");
                  break;
      
     case "slide": console.log("Slide action here");
                  break; 
      
     
     default :console.log("any other actions here")
  
  
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" onclick="tasks('fade')">Fade</div>
 <div id="demo" onclick="tasks('glow')">Glow</div>
<div id="demo" onclick="tasks('slide')">Slide</div>
<div id="demo" onclick="tasks('any other')">any other</div>
```

Comment: Thanks any other way to do this

Comment: You can also use `switch` statements like shown in the other answer

Comment: Thanks i will try this to is there any way to declare this like variable

Comment: What if i want multiple action like function(task task2)

Comment: Modify like this `onclick="tasks('fade','glow')"` and your function like this: `function tasks(action1, action2){....}`

Comment: Why would I use a single function with a parameter telling it what to do, instead of three functions named `fade` etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable which be available in your function:

```
<script>
 function tasks(effect){
 switch(effect){
  case "fade":
    // execute some code here;
    break;
  case "glow":
    // execute some code here;
    break;
  case "slide":
    // execute some code here;
    break;
}
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: is there any way to declare like variable

Comment: This is a local variable which you can use in this function and this variable passed when onclick happened.

Comment: Ok thanks For help My problem is Resolved Both codes helped me thanks

Comment: mark your question as resolved - so other users will know that this answer already closed.

Comment: what if i want to triger more than one tasks

Comment: In this case you can pass few variables into onclick - onclick="tasks('fade', 'glow')" and use this variables in your function - function tasks(effect1, effect2) ...